# Set syntax for current file in PHPStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

Simple question: Can I make PHPStorm to display the current file with a certain syntax highlighting?

Maybe even make the IDE remember it for that particular file in that particular project?

Background: I got a Laravel `.env` file which I'd like to display with the highlighting for .ini files without generally setting that highlighting for all .env files.

Comment: Generally speaking -- No. Possible options for your `.env` (all done by assigning (at IDE level) to that File Type anyway): 1) give unique extension for such files. It could be actually unique extension (e.g. `.inienv`) which is hard to use/convience somebody to start using; or double extension (e.g. `.ini.env`) which you can almost always use; 2) unique file name pattern (similar to double extension (in general) .. but much longer .. up to the point when it completely covers whole name (e.g. `special.env` -- all files named like that will be assigned to that specific file type).

Comment: Man that's a pity. Well I guess I can live with that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Probably you can write plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set manually the syntax highlighting of any file in PhpStorm.
[image: See screenshot]

1. 'Ctrl+,' or File-> Preferences to open Settings.
2. File Types -> Recognized File Types
3. Open needed Syntax format, 'INI config' in your and 'XML' in my case
4. '+' in File name patterns
5. Set the filename you need to highlight, e.g. '.env.example' or 'someMask.*' or 'managed-schema' for Solr
6. Apply and close settings to see your file is already highlighted